# Suspicious .nyiyeverc file in my home directory

Tags: macos, malware

I found a suspicious hidden file on my Mac (a ppc powerbook running 10.4.11) when cleaning house recently. It's an 8 kb Unix executable file named ".nyiyeverc" sitting in my home directory (~/).
I searched its name on google, duckduckgo, even bing, but got nothing. Furthermore, I took a peek at it's contents by opening it in TextEdit (which in retrospect sounds like a foolish move, but I did it). In TextEdit it appears to be a single line that reads "awcnsawcnsawcnsawcnsawoolwascully wa". I plugged that string into search engines too with no results.
It looks like it was created 2/19/12 and last modified two days ago, 9/26/12, which leads me to believe that whatever it is, it's been up to something on a regular basis for the last seven months.
Any ideas what this might be and what I should do about it? For the time being I've moved it into a "quarantined" folder I made elsewhere in my home directory. I'm considering just deleting it, but don't know if that'd solve anything or break something. Help is appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Does the filename reference "new years" i y "eve" rc (.nyiyeverc)? What could "iy" be?

Comment: There's `cn` in there, a sure sign of Chinese hackers! (I'm kidding)

Comment: You could see what processes access it by running `sudo opensnoop -f ~/.nyiyeverc` in Terminal and keeping the window open for a few days.

Comment: @LauriRanta - i got "sudo: opensnoop: command not found" :P  I guess I don't have opensnoop on my machine. Sounds like it came with 10.5. Is there a way I could install it?

Comment: Maybe just rename it and move it.  See if another is created? Btw, now a google search brings up a lot!  All you :)

Comment: @Josh Good idea. I did move it, but didn't think to rename it. And checking my home folder now, it hasn't reappeared (yet). Thanks :)