# Unknown files in my home folder

Tags: macos, malware

I was looking around in Terminal and suddenly spotted 2 suspicious files in my home folder, one with the same content as [mentioned here](https://superuser.com/questions/481062/suspicious-nyiyeverc-file-in-my-home-directory) but with different name. I deleted it in a hurry, so can't collect any more info on it. The other file is called `.nzceqsan` and when opened with Vim it contains only:

```
sufferinsuccotash
```

I ran `mdls` on it to get meta data, and it produced this:

```
kMDItemFSContentChangeDate = 2013-11-25 21:02:05 +0000
kMDItemFSCreationDate      = 2013-11-25 21:02:05 +0000
kMDItemFSCreatorCode       = ""
kMDItemFSFinderFlags       = 0
kMDItemFSHasCustomIcon     = 0
kMDItemFSInvisible         = 1
kMDItemFSIsExtensionHidden = 0
kMDItemFSIsStationery      = 0
kMDItemFSLabel             = 0
kMDItemFSName              = ".nzceqsan"
kMDItemFSNodeCount         = 17
kMDItemFSOwnerGroupID      = 20
kMDItemFSOwnerUserID       = 501
kMDItemFSSize              = 17
kMDItemFSTypeCode          = ""
```

I am not sure how to interpret all of that, but I see it was created a long time ago and haven't changed since. Question is, is my system hacked? How can I gather more information? How can I prevent this from happening again?

**Edit:**

I found a [couple tweets](https://twitter.com/search?q=sufferin%20succotash%20%40SketchUp&src=typd) saying they got a similar file when installing Sketchup. I haven't found any confirmation about this from SketchUp yet.

Comment: That phrase is known as an expression of annoyance and surprise by animated cartoon characters such as Sylvester the Cat and Daffy Duck. Not enough information to judge if you are hacked. But you shouldn't ignore even small suspicious things because sometimes it is all you find... all in all i would investigate more into it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succotash – not enough context.

Comment: Thanks @monsune. I thought it might have been a signature of some kind, from a hacker/malware. And if anyone else have experienced or seen it before they would recognize it. It turns out it might come from install of SketchUp. Updated my question with the info and have sent an email to SketchUp to get it confirmed.

Comment: What user on your system owns that file in question?

Comment: @Richie086 my user is the owner of the file.

Comment: I have a succotash file, and another file containing: `awoesawoesawoesawoesawoesawoesawoesawoesawoesawoesawoesawcrywascully wab`  It's good to know that these are from sketchup and not some virus, but seriously sketchup folks, what's this about!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received confirmation from SketchUp support. The file was created by an earlier version of SketchUp Pro. Newer versions of SketchUp Pro does not create this suspicious file.

So if you find a hidden file with a strange filename, in your home folder, that contains only `sufferinsuccotash` - it is from SketchUp Pro 2014 or earlier.

Comment: Thanks for looking deeper into this. I had a similar file on my system and wondered where it came from... research brought me to your post and now it's clear - I also have an older version of SketchUp installed on my Mac.